# how to write conditional counts with playa?

Tags: playa

Hi I am using playa on a real estate site.

I have properties listed with the realtor that is selling the property and I can get that working fine with playa. My issue is when I have a property that has two realtors selling it. I can listing both of them fine, but I want to have them displayed in an accordion if there are more than one realtor.

This is the code I have thus far :

```
 {exp:playa:children}
 {if count == "1"}
 <ul class="agent">
 <li class="name">{title}</li>
 <li class="phone">{phone}</li>
 <li class="mail">{agent_email}</li>
 </ul>
 {if:else}
 <div class="accordion">
 <h3 class="name">{title}</h3>
 <div>
 <ul class="agent">
 <li class="phone">{phone}</li>
 <li class="mail">{agent_email}</li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
 {/if}
 {/exp:playa:children}
```

What I am seeing is single realtors being listed fine, but when there are two realtors it lists the first one as a single and puts the second realtor in the accordion.

Any help would be great, I have been trying to figure this out for a while and can't seem to quite get there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using `total_results` instead of `count`?

```
{exp:playa:children}
    {if total_results == "1"}
        <ul class="agent">
            <li class="name">{title}</li>
            <li class="phone">{phone}</li>
            <li class="mail">{agent_email}</li>
        </ul>
    {if:else}
        <div class="accordion">
            <h3 class="name">{title}</h3>
            <div>
                <ul class="agent">
                    <li class="phone">{phone}</li>
                    <li class="mail">{agent_email}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    {/if}
{/exp:playa:children}
```